# Flutter and Firestore: How can I get the document Id from the add function?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, web, google-cloud-firestore

I added a document to Firestore. How can I get the document Id of my added document? I want to save it to a variable.

Btw. I'm using this for a web app if this Is important.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('room').add({
    'name': _name,
    'points': 0,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this

```
User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('room').add({
    'id': user.uid,
    'name': _name,
    'points': 0,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `.then` method at the end.

Do what ever you need with docRef.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('room').add({
    'name': _name,
    'points': 0,
}).then(function(docRef) {
    console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The `add` method on `CollectionReference` returns a `Future<DocumentReference>`. [[Documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/CollectionReference/add.html)]

```dart
Future<DocumentReference> add(Map<String, dynamic> data) async {
  final DocumentReference newDocument = doc();
  await newDocument.set(data);
  return newDocument;
}
```

So, try this:

```dart
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('room')
  .add({
    'name': _name,
    'points': 0,
  })
  .then((docRef) => print(docRef.id));
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling [`CollectionReference.add`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/CollectionReference/add.html) returns a `Future<DocumentReference>`, so you can get the ID from that:

```
var newDocRef = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('room').add({
    'name': _name,
    'points': 0,
})
var newDocId = newDocRef.id
```

---

If you want to store the ID inside the document, it's better to first create the `DocumentReference` by calling `CollectionReference.doc()` without paramters:

```
var newDocRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('room').doc();
var newDocId = newDocRef.id
newDocRef.set({
    'id': newDocId,
    'name': _name,
    'points': 0,
})
```